# Determinant of a sparse matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, sparse-matrices

Suppose
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1&&&\\ 1&0&0&-1&\ddots\\ &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&1&0&0&-1\\ &&&1&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

For an $n \times n$ matrix, I see that the inverse of $A$ does not always exist. I am not sure but it looks like a Heisenberg matrix.

If $n$ is divisible by $3$, then I see that $\det(A)=1$. For any other $n$, $\det(A)=0$ and thus $A$ is non-invertible. Not sure if there is a general formula that can show this?

For example a $9 \times 9$ matrix is like the following
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the lazy comment - is there no nice pattern to the cofactor expansions along the top row/first column?

Comment: $A$ seems rectangular to me

Comment: Hmm i think i messed with latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is correct then your $\LaTeX$ has two extra columns at the end that you should delete. Also, you mean [Hessenberg matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).

Anyway, because the matrix is so sparse this is actually quite straightforward to do by cofactor expansion. Write $M_n$ for this matrix. If you cofactor expand along the first two columns you end up with a matrix with first row $-1, 0, 0, \dots$ and if you then cofactor expand along this row you find that

$$\det M_n = - \det M_{n-3}.$$

Now it suffices to compute $\det M_1 = 0, \det M_2 = 0, \det M_3 = -1$; we get

$$\det M_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } & 3 \nmid n \\ (-1)^{\frac{n}{3}} & \text{ if } & 3 \mid n \end{cases}$$